# How to consume data from Azure eventhub using Spark with Java

Tags: java, azure, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

There are tutorials available for receiving events from azure eventhub that are solely written using JAVA

But I not getting any help on writing **azure eventhub consumer code using spark with java**

Can anyone please help with some tutorials or guide me to right direction ?

Comment: This is the project you need: https://github.com/hdinsight/spark-eventhubs . it has examples in scala, not java, but those should be interoperable.

Comment: Thanks @itaysk..as mentioned it is in scala and it takes time for me to convert it to JAVA as I dont want to use both..Also, I read here [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) to write your own custom receiver that I can plugged in with JavaReceiverInputDStream receiverStream method...But here also I am unable to figure out host and port in case of EventHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions in this article to consume an Azure Event Hub using Java from within Spark.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph

However, if you are trying to created a long-running Spark Streaming job I'd suggest writing your jobs in Scala, not Java.  I too had jobs written in Java and when we decided to swap from Kafka to Azure Event Hubs for your messaging queue.  We were able to get connect to the Event Hub using the Direct Receiver approach, translated from Scala to Java based on this aticle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-eventhub-streaming, however working with the resulting stream proved difficult in Java.

Good luck!